# Identifying machine uniquely: Is it necessary to have one hostname per machine

Tags: networking, network-programming

I need to uniquely identify a machine despite it having multiple IP addresses(*which a common scenarios for linux machines*) what I am thinking of is to use hostname as an identifier for the machine/system(host name in `/etc/hostname`). Is it mandatory that a system will have only one `hostname` or a system can have multiple host names.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would identify it as some combination of hostname, MAC address, processor serial number, and hardware serial number.  This may not be possible with virtualization, though a virtualized machine *should* have a unique MAC, unless someone has duplicated it.

Also, I'd get the hostname with uname -n rather than parsing /etc/hostname.  Not all Unixes (HP-UX) use /etc/hostname, so this increases portability.

Answer (score -1):

f.e your host is connected to networks 192.168.1.12 and 10.0.1.14

Edit your **/etc/hosts** with

**192.168.1.12 ethhost**

**10.0.1.14 wlanhost**

Now you will be able to ping your host with both names ethhost and wlanhost

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  What you wrote is correct - this will allow someone to ping the machine using both names - but this is not what the guy asked for.  He wants to identify a machine, not ping it.